# Input count Java

Tags: java, exception, java.util.scanner

When i started programming, I used to practise on silly exercises like this one:

**Desired behavior:**
"Digit an arbitrary chosen number of Strings on the terminal, and then count them, if they are not numbers."

Example of Strings digited:

> "I", "am", "3", "times", "better", "than", "be", "4"

**Result expected:** `6`

**Correct code:**

```
    ArrayList<String> container = new ArrayList<>();
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int number = 0;

    while (number == 0) {
        System.out.println("Digit an arbitrary positive number: ");

        try {
            number = Integer.parseInt(input.next());
            if (number == 0) { throw new Exception(); }
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            System.out.println(" Exception: You didn't digit correctly! ");
        }
    }

    for (int i=0; i<number; i++ ){
        System.out.println("Enter a String : ");
        String next = input.next();
        try {
            Integer.parseInt(next);
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            container.add(next);
        }
    }
    System.out.println("You digited " + container.size() + " Strings! ");
```

Comment: `input.nextLine` will not execute after `input.hasNextInt`.

Comment: I doubt this even compiles, due to the use of `i` on line 1.

Comment: The `while` simply doesn't make any sense at all.

Comment: Can somebody tell me how to do and why is it wrong?

Comment: Does it compile? Does it throw an error or is it just behaving unexpectedly? What did you see? Did you try to debug it? --- "Can somebody tell me ...". Yes we could, but you don't pay us enough for that and you wouldn't learn anything ;)

Comment: Well... for one... "i" only exists inside your for loop... other than that, you have a lot to do.

Comment: simple use input.hasNext() instead of input.hasNextInt();

Comment: Why don't you start by trying to write a program which will read a single line from the input and split it in words?

Comment: Is this all of the code? People are saying it won't compile because i is only in the for loop but it's not actually declared there so must be further up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ArrayList<String> arr = new ArrayList<String>();
while (input.hasNext()){
   String str = input.next();
   try{
       int garbage = Integer.parseInt(str); //this will fail if it's not a number
   }
   catch Exception e{
       arr.add(str);// that means we want to keep it
   }

}
```

Now you just want to print all the strings in arr, and return it's size as the number of words you kept.
Probably not the best approach, but should work fine.